# Sending json with cURL doesn't echo the result back, why?

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to send this POST request and it won't echo any result,
I've tried to use different techniques but it's either giving me 500 error or just stuck on a blank page, whereas it should echo back at least something like this:

```
{"errorCode":"APP-0001","message":"Something really bad happened. Please contact your administrator, right now!","fields":{},"operationMessage":"Something really bad happened. Please contact your administrator, right now!"}
```

```
<?php


$countryCode = $_POST['countryCode'];
$phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];


$data = array("countryCode" => "$countryCode", "phoneNumber" => "$phoneNumber");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('https://consumer-edge-service.careem.com/api/v8/user/partialSignup?device=ACMA');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: SCBOHw6OOZD1lOJyS2dz',
    'Agent: ACMA',
    'User-Agent: ACMA/8.7.7',
    'Device: ' . $phoneNumber,
    'Provider-Access-Key: 6ba82ffa',
    'Version: 8772',
    'x-careem-position: 29.452370,32.752543,1799.999023,1552014765404',
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Content-Length: 46',
    'Host: consumer-edge-service.careem.com',
    'Connection: close',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'X-NewRelic-ID: VQMAWFVVABAHVVBXDwgFVA==')
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: `$result` is probably `false`, indicating a problem with the actual request. You should try `if ($result === false) echo curl_error($ch);`

Comment: Didn't work man :(

Comment: there are loads of SSL options with curl , as well as the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` option that you could use to see what gives.  AFAIK they all work man :)